# Rails cookies with chinese characters causes wrong string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cookies, encode

I develop app with rails 4 + and angular 1.2.14. When I try to save a chinese username to cookie. And I read it via angularjs $cookieStore. I get a strange string which is unreadable, basically, I think it's the problem of cookie itself can't directly save chinese chracters. But I can't find a proper way to solve it. Even I use string.force_encoding('UTF-8'), nothing happened. Below it the core code about this question.

This is what I store cookie data in ruby controller file:

`cookies[:user] = user_info(user)`

user_info method is defined as follows:

  `def user_info(user)
    {
        id: user.id.to_s,
        username: user.username,
        role: user.role,
        expires: 1.hour.from_now
    }.to_json
  end`

And I get it in angular services with $cookieStore injected before:

`_current_user = $cookieStore.get('user')`

when I watch this _current_user, the english characters like field id and role are right. But the username I get is a strange string `é¾é­`.

Is the problem caused by cookie save chinese characters itself, or just caused by angular?

It troubles me a few hours. Thank for those who answer it.